# function in referenced .js file in script source tag is not executed

Tags: javascript

JavaScript beginner question:
So, I'm learning online and ran across a tutorial with the following codes for the .html file. I attempted to run everything locally on my computer. Following was what I did:

Step 1: Created .html file and placed the following codes inside

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>External JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>(myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScript.js").
</p>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Step 2: 
Created a .js file and placed the following codes inside:

```
 function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
 }
```

Step 3:
Executed .html file via Chrome but function in .js file called by command in .html file doesn't execute

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Try to put a console.log("in here") inside the myfunction() and see the console.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me copying the code exactly how you typed it above and pasting them into new files.

When the page start up it looks like this:

[image]

And then when I click the button the text changes to "Paragraph changed":

[image]

I don't see any errors in the console either.

What are you expecting to happen? What is actually happening when you run it that is not the expected functionality?

Also, please check that both files are in the same directory. If you wanted to put the js files in different directories then you would need to reference the relative path in your script tag. For example, if your folder structure looked like this:

[image]

then a valid script tag would be this:

`<script src="./js-files/myScript.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried with relative path for both files on desktop (script src="/users/bob/desktop/myScript.js" and script src="myScript.js") and both files within a subdirectory of desktop - which didn't work. The file path, for some reason, worked for HTML img src. HTML file ran well for me, so it displayed with the button. What didnt' happen is when I clicked the button - nothing happens. Host platform: MacOs X (just in case)

Comment: Hmm did you try with only the "dot slash"? (src="./myScript.js")
Which browsers are you trying?